# disconnect/remove/delete existing mutation observers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, proxy, mutation-observers

I am working on proxy site with 3rd party lib that create multiple mutation observers on page load, that are not accessible from console level. My question is - can I somehow delete or disconnect them without excluding that lib or some parts of it's code? - Re-observing node with a different function is not working for me.

Comment: You can probably recreate the DOM nodes used by those observers.

Comment: not helping - it is observing body

Comment: Hmm, spoof `window.MutationObserver` on page start (before that library) with your own wrapper that will disconnect the observers when the page is loaded.